# Python selenium browser accepts cookies and returns`AttributeError`

Tags: python, parsing, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm scraping data from a sports website. This is one of the pages, where the code gets stuck:

https://www.unitedrugby.com/clubs/dhl-stormers/kwenzo-blose

When opening it with an incognito browser you'll see a Cookies window where one must accept the cookies. Here's how I do it:

```py
driver.get(url)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

WebDriverWait(driver, 8).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='flex items-center justify-center py-2.5 px-[18px] lg:px-[22px] border border-solid rounded-tl-lg rounded-br-lg text-base lg:text-xl tracking-[2px] font-urc-sans transition ease-linear duration-300 border-turquoise-primary bg-turquoise-primary bg-opacity-[0.08] text-slate-deep hover:text-turquoise-secondary mx-auto md:order-last md:ml-4 md:mr-0']"))
)

WebDriverWait(driver, 8).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button/span[contains(., 'ACCEPT ALL')]"))
).click()

el = driver.get_attribute("outerHTML")
el = BeautifulSoup(el, "html.parser")

...
```

I'm not a pro with selenium, I'm still learning, so I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. It either gets stuck at the cookies window, or it crashes at the `.get_attribute()` call by saying:

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'
```

There are > 800 players which have a page in this website, and I have successfully scraped the data of many of them every week. They must have changed something in the website's architecture but even today some of the scrapings of other players went fine, and then this one just doesn't want to be scraped.

I hope someone can shed some light on the issue for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_attribute` - this method is related to Web Element and not Web Driver.

Change the below line:

```
el = driver.get_attribute("outerHTML")
```

To:

```
el = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*")
el = el.get_attribute("outerHTML")
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot. The distinction wasn't yet clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Websites often change code. That's why it's important to have maintainable code. And with less code, there's less to maintain.

In full disclosure, I'm the author of the [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) package. [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) is lightweight, less verbose extension of the Selenium web driver that makes browser automation even easier. Simply install the package with `pip install browserist`.

This snippet of code opens the URL and accepts cookies so the cookie banner closes:

```py
from browserist import Browser

browser = Browser()
browser.open.url("https://www.unitedrugby.com/clubs/dhl-stormers/kwenzo-blose")
browser.click.button("//*[@id='__nuxt']/div/div/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/button[1]")

driver = browser._browser_driver

el = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*")
el = el.get_attribute("outerHTML")
```

Notes:

- You can get the Selenium web driver with `browser._browser_driver` so you can continue with Beautiful Soup.
- [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) doesn't need explicit conditions like `WebDriverWait`, `expected_conditions` or `element_to_be_clickable` – it's already built in so you don't have to worry about it. Instead, [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) awaits an element to be fully loaded before it interacts with it. More on this concept [here](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/#difference-from-selenium).

Here's what I get (slowed down as [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) finishes the job almost in a blink of an eye). I hope this is helpful. Let me know if you have questions?

[image: Screen capture of Browserist in action]